# Prevent cables and wires from twisting

Tags: organization, cables, wire

My desktop computer has lots of wires behind it. Some wires are tangled. How can I keep these wires from tangling?

I don't want to put the cables together & tie them using a string or something like that, because I need to unplug/plug existing wires and add new cables from time to time according to my requirements.

Comment: Hello Kushan Randima! I may be misunderstanding your problem, but perhaps wrapping the cable in floss or tape(duct tape, perhaps) will help the situation. This stops some cords from twisting and may help your cables.

Comment: Similar: [How can I keep my desktop computer's cables neat?](http://lifehacks.stackexchange.com/questions/3956/how-can-i-keep-my-desktop-computers-cables-neat) and [How can I keep cables from falling off of desks when unplugged?](http://lifehacks.stackexchange.com/questions/2469/how-can-i-keep-cables-from-falling-off-of-desks-when-unplugged)

Comment: Not a lifehack, but I've used [Apple cores](http://www.apple-cores.com/) for my desk. Much preferable to the cable clutter.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The simple answer is to untangle them and be careful when adding and removing cables. When you first plug everything in, make sure the cables aren't crossed. Move from left to right or top to bottom.

If that isn't sufficient or is too much of a pain to remember there are a few additional things that you can do to keep things straight.

1. For cables that you routinely add and remove, consider using one of the methods here to keep the plugs from falling: [How can I keep cables from falling off of desks when unplugged?](https://lifehacks.stackexchange.com/questions/2469/how-can-i-keep-cables-from-falling-off-of-desks-when-unplugged)
2. Coil and secure cables that are longer than needed.

   - You can use short lengths of velcro as removable cable ties.  Double sided [velcro](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Velcro) (hook on one side, loop on the other) can be found in most fabric stores, sold in spools or by the yard.
3. Consider securing cables to the underside of your desk.

   - You can use thumbtacks or screws and lengths of velcro to secure cables to the underside of your desk like this:

     [image][image]
   - Or you can make a similar arrangement using binder clips:
     [image]

Comment: Nice idea of binder clip

Answer (score 2):

It's not a good idea to coil power cables.

Coiling power cables creates a magnetic field. The more turns and the tighter (neater) the cable is, the stronger the magnetic field.

Data cables have built-in twists to minimize electrical interference from such outside sources. Even so, data cables have more errors when they are near magnetic fields than when there is no magnetic interference.

A disorganized random jumble of cables with no coils is preferable from a data integrity point of view. Jumbles of cables collect dust and dirt and are difficult to clean. They can be a problem when you are trying to troubleshoot.

What to do?

Put the whole mess into a clean laundry or garbage bag and tie the bag so that cables are contained. For maintenance, you can dust around and under the bag. Leave only as much cable as you need outside the bag. Long ends can be secured as shown here by others.

To find and trace the cables, label both ends of the cables with matching tags by colour, letters, numbers, or names before you start the project to make them easy to locate.